Dao Query Annotates some Room Table Names
I am just curious on why some entity table names are autocompleted with grave accent quotes `` and but the other table names on Dao Query.
Take a look at these tables:
Entity 1
@Entity(tableName = "account")
data class AccountEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: String,
    .... )

Entity 2
@Entity(tableName = "transaction")
data class TransactionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) 
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") 
    val id: String,
    ..... )

Dao Query

Why is it that transaction is annotated with `` and not account or category tables on the above Dao Query?


Why is it that transaction is annotated with '' and not account or category tables on the above Dao Query?

First they are not ''s (single quotes) but `'s (grave accents).
Transaction is an SQLite keyword and thus an invalid table name hence the need for it to be enclosed.
You may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html for a more comprehensive explanation.

Thanks @MikeT for the tip on SQL reserved words, very helpful.
